# errors when doing an nw install with latest node.js

Tags: node.js, nwjs

I have been using nw for a number of years. I recently updated node.js to 19.3.0 and am wanting to update nw in my projects. When I do the following:
npm install nw@0.72.0-sdk
I get a number of deprecate messages and then a 404 error. After starting the command I do see the nodemodules folder being created, but it is later deleted. The first error appearing is this:

3602 verbose stack Error: command failed
3602 verbose stack at ChildProcess. (/Users/csrf/.nvm/versions/node/v19.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:53:27)

I am wondering whether I need to revert to an earlier version of node.js and nw?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce. I changed my Node version to `19.3.0`. Made an empty folder and ran this in it:

`echo > index.html && npm init -y && npm pkg set devDependencies.nw="0.72.0-sdk" && npm pkg set main="index.html" && npm pkg set scripts.start="nw ." && npm install && npm start`

Worked without any issues. Other than the usual audit notice:

```
added 119 packages, and audited 120 packages in 1m

8 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

4 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 2 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I'm assuming you just had a bad internet connect, or the server that hosts the NW.js binaries was being flaky (I've seen reports of this before). Just delete the `node_modules` and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much for checking this. Deleting node_modules did not work unfortunately. I have a lot of dependencies in my package.json file. I am going to follow what you did, and build up again stepwise.

Comment: Really stuck with this problem - simple Hello World index.html, a package.json with this dependency - "devDependencies": {
    "nw": "^0.72.0-sdk"
  }, and a .nprmc with fetch-retries=3
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 6000000
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 1000000.                                         
I get: 682 error code 1
683 error path /Users/csrf/Documents/Git-Repos/VerySimple/verysimple/node_modules/nw
684 error command failed
685 error command sh -c node scripts/install.js
686 error Response code 404 (Not Found)
687 verbose exit 1 689 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1676384048821

Answer (score 0):

This command has enabled the installation of nw:

```bash
npm_config_nwjs_process_arch=x64 npm install nw@0.72.0-sdk --verbose
```

Came from this issue report:
https://github.com/nwjs/npm-installer/issues/83